# How to create a sharp image in android

Tags: android, xml, image

I am designing an android app and I need to implement the following interface.  I need a round border around this number.  For the round border I am using an image with a circle with a gradient border.  For the numbers I am using the `textview`.  The problem that I have is that when I debug it, the numbers extremely sharp and clean but the circle is not that sharp. The borders look quite rough.   I took a screenshot of it but on the phone the thing is much more evident.  I also noticed this when I was using an image and a background.  The picture in the background was much more clear than the image on the screen.  How can I fix this.

[image]

This is the XML that I am using

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/b"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that image sharpness but you should consider on below points with your `ImageView`,

- Setting the image to the ImageView using `android:src="..."` rather than `android:background="..."`. `src=` makes it scale the image maintaining aspect ratio!
- You should also use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to make the `ImageView` resize itself to fit the resealed image.
- You can change the way it default scales images using the `android:scaleType` parameter, use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and see if it gets more clear.